# looking vim plugin like QT controlling '' "" {} [] <> ()?

Tags: vim-plugin

I am looking for a  vim plugin is about controlling symbol ( '' "" {} [] <> () ) like QT-creator.

`Insert mode when i press "  , then  "|"  is available in the screen.`

`Insert mode when i press ""  , then  ""|  is available in the screen.`

`Insert mode when i press (  , then  (|)  is availavle in the screen.`

`Insert mode when i press ()  , then  ()|  is availavle in the screen.`

Something like that.

Anyone knows what i am talking about and know about that? Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [autopairs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599). It seems to do what you want.